# Error : Crud using Nodejs express and Mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, fetch, crud

I'm facing an issue in my project I tried to do CRUD using MVC but when I run the code it doesn't return any data from db, the connection works fine I don't know why it doesn't work. I'm using NodeJS Express and mysql.

here is my code :

**index.js:**

```
db.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
  }
  console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
});

const usersRouter= require("./routes/routes");

app.use("/api/", usersRouter)
```

**routes.js:**

```
// get latest record of airMonitoring 
router.get("/", airController.getAllData);
```

**Model.js:**

```
const AirMonitoring = function(table){
    this.id = table.id;
    this.Temperature = table.Temperature;
    this.Humidity = table.Humidity;
    this.AirCondition = table.AirCondition;

}
// get all data from airMonitoring


    AirMonitoring.getAllData = ( result) =>{
        db.query('SELECT * FROM AirMonitoring', (err, res)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log('Error while fetching airMonitoring', err);
                result(err, null);
            }else{
                console.log('AirMonitoring fetched successfully');
                result(res, null);
            }
        })
        }
```

**Controller.js:**

```
exports.getAllData = (req, res)=> {
   
    AirModel.getAllData((err, airMonitoring) =>{
        if(err)
        res.send(err);
        console.log('data', airMonitoring);
        res.send(airMonitoring)
    })
}
```

and the error received from postman :

[image]

error Console :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to return your `res` call in your `if (err)` statement. If you don't add a return it will proceed to execute the codes that follows.

```
if(err) return res.send(err);
```

Then again, your error stemmed from something before this.

Comment: I tried to edit it but still now it retruns : Error while fetching airMonitoring Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Comment: then it's your mysql error